# Send Notification and save info to database

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that sends out a notification when a client fills out the form. I know would like to be able to save this information in my database table but am having an issue. It doesn't save a copy to the database at all unless I clear out my model. here's what the controller and model look like.

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contact = Contact.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @contact }
    end
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

    if verify_recaptcha(request.remote_ip, params)[:status] == 'false'
      render 'index', :layout => '/layouts/application.html.erb'
  elsif
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to("/contact", :notice => 'Your Message was successfully sent.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "index" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @contact.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end

end
```

model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :email, :phone, :phone_type, :address, :fullName, :content, :userBrowser, :userOS

  attr_accessor :id, :email, :phone, :phone_type, :address, :fullName, :content, :userBrowser, :userOS

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

  def to_key
  end

  def save
    if self.valid?
      Notifier.contact_notification(self).deliver
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your overriding so much of the parent methods, all you should need to make the notifier work is

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :email, :phone, :phone_type, :address, :fullName, :content, :userBrowser, :userOS

  after_save :send_contact_notification

  def send_contact_notification
    Notifier.contact_notification(self).deliver
  end
end
```

Also you shouldn't have to include the Validations, they're available already, and if your trying to protect the model fields, you probably want attr_accessible not attr_accessor, since the later is taken care of by ActiveRecord already.

Comment: I had originally followed a tutorial online that only emailed the data, it did not store it, being new at rails, I'm still trying to figure out how it all works.